# Typescript: declare custom typings for functions of a library

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I want to improve the typings of a typescript library, so my team actually knows what parameters are expected.

currently, the parameters are typed as `string`, but in our project we only want to use our defined `string enums`. i'd like to change the parameters' type so the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) shows that our enums are expected as parameters, since `string` is kinda arbitrary.

---

let's say i have a function like this from the library:

```
export function findProperty(propertyGroup: PropertyGroup, type: string, key: string, path?: string[]): Property<string>;
```

which i want to change to:

```
export function findProperty(propertyGroup: PropertyGroup, type: string, key: MyKeyEnum, path?: MyPathEnum[]): Property<string>;
```

i've tried using `tsconfig.json`s' `typeRoots` and declared a module with the same name as the libraries' module. this kinda worked, but only for one of my multi-module projects' modules. the other modules do not show the updated function definitions, even though they all extend the same tsconfig.

---

my tsconfig:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "src/@types"
  ],
},
"files": [
  "src/@types/@company/angular-util/hierarchy-types.types.ts"
],
...
```

my hierarchy-types.types.ts:

```
declare module '@company/angular-util' {
  export function findProperty(propertyGroup: PropertyGroup, type: string, key: MyKeyEnum, path?: MyPathEnum[]): Property<string>;
}
```

---

my project structure looks like this:

- src

  - **tsconfig.json** // base tsconfig, all tsconfigs below extend from this one
  - @types
  - libs // the declarations work in this folder

    - beans

      - **tsconfig.json**
    - store

      - **tsconfig.json**
    - ...

      - **tsconfig.json**
- themes

  - blue

    - **tsconfig.json**
  - red

    - **tsconfig.json**
- ui // angular application - declaration does not work here

  - **tsconfig.json**
  - src

---

Why doesn't my declaration work in the ui folder?

Comment: Have you added your `enum` to exports in the public API file (`public-api.ts`)? Cause typescript will automatically generate typing for you

Comment: @PankajSati yes, my enums are exported and present in the ```public-api.ts```. however, those enums are created in my own project, not in the library. the library does not know they exist. i just want to declare the same functions the library provides with my enums as parameters, as i already know they work with my enums.